# How to implement andengine surfacegesturedetector adapter in gles2?

Tags: android, andengine

I want to implement swipe gestures in my game.  search on net but not accurate result found.
Please anyone help me to implement **surfacegesturedetectorAdapter** in **andengine gles2**.

The logcate say:

*"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"*

I also tried onUiThread method but it isn't work.
if anyone found solution please help.....
THANS....in adv.

Comment: sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call below method inside onloadScene() :

```
private void setupGestureDetaction(){

SurfaceGestureDetector surfaceGestureDetector = new SurfaceGestureDetector(1f) {

@Override
 protected boolean onSwipeUp() {
 System.out.println("onSwipeUp");
 return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean onSwipeRight() {
System.out.println("onSwipeRight");
return true;
}

 @Override
 protected boolean onSwipeLeft() {
 System.out.println("onSwipeLeft");
 return true;
 }

@Override
 protected boolean onSwipeDown() {
 System.out.println("onSwipeDown");
 return true;
 }

@Override
 protected boolean onSingleTap() {
 System.out.println("onSingleTap");
 return true;
}

 @Override
  protected boolean onDoubleTap() {
  System.out.println("onDoubleTap");
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onManagedTouchEvent(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {    
  return super.onManagedTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);
 }

@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,
  TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {    
  return super.onSceneTouchEvent(pScene, pSceneTouchEvent);
}
};

    surfaceGestureDetector.setEnabled(true);


  mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(surfaceGestureDetector);
 }
```

In above method you need to make your modifications as per your need.

Comment: THANKS FOR REPLY....but this code set The constructor SurfaceGestureDetector(float) is undefined error...

Comment: Check this : http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/input/touch/detector/SurfaceGestureDetector.java?r=7d81e830fea0a8bfaac9cc185301e9823ea38092

Comment: Thanks ....... i think... i take idea from this link.. (And yes, i agree with you for this "I hate down voters. They keep down voting instead of answering / helping. Simply they don't know meaning of STACKOVERFLOW...") vote up my Q as research effort or useful.... THANKS AGAIN....

Comment: If above answer is helpful for you, then you should upvote it so other can follow the same answer.

Comment: I haven't reputation for up vote your answer.... but sure to up vote when i reach needed reputation..... coool